# access elements of dataframes in list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm new to R, trying to understand how to access elements of my dataframe when I add them to a list.

I can access the elements of the dataframe normally but can't do the same when I add the dataframe to the list. How can I do it? Thanks

```
abc <- rbind(presence[2,], presence[6,], presence[9,])
bca <- rbind(presence[5,], presence[7,], presence[10,])
cab <- rbind(presence[4,], presence[8,], presence[12,])

abc[1,7] #works

sets <- list(abc, bca, cab)
sets$abc[1,7] #returns NULL
```

Comment: Your list elements don't have names. You can access them by index: `sets[[1]][1, 7]` or give them names as akrun suggests.

Comment: You may also benefit from reading [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) on creating a list of data.frames. My answer there shows how the `mget` function can be used to construct named lists of objects when there names follow some pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no

```
sets$abc
```

as the `list` is unnamed

We need to `name` it

```
names(sets) <- c('abc', 'bca', 'cab')
```

---

Or when creating the `list` use

```
sets <- list(abc = abc, bca = bca, cab = cab)
```

With `purrr`, the naming is automatically done with `lst`

```
sets <- purrr::lst(abc, bca, cab)
```

Or use `dplyr::lst`

```
sets <-  dplyr::lst(abc, bca, cba)
```

---

Instead of extracting each element one by one, this can be also done with `lapply/sapply`

```
lapply(sets, `[`, 1, 7)
```

Or with `sapply` to return a `vector`

```
sapply(sets, `[`, 1, 7)
```